# Invalidating zero in front of the currency regex

Tags: regex

So far I can validate currency up to certain point but there is a problem.

My current regex: `/^[0-9]\d{0,7}+\.?\d{2}$/`

These should not be validated (This is what I cannot implement). **No zero(s) in front accepted, unless it is like 0.50, 0.15 etc.**

```
0123456.00
0123.55
```

**Validity rule:**

- Before dot sign: Max 8 numerics.
- After dot: 2 numerics compulsory.
- Dot is compulsory too.

**So all these are valid:**

```
0.00
0.10
1.00
12345678.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this pattern `^(?!0\d)\d{1,8}\.\d{2}$`
[demo](http://regex101.com/r/rD0rW2)

Comment: You don't cover `1.1` and `0.1`

Comment: as I shouldn't 1.1 and 0.1 has only one digit after dot!